# Rails - build_association is not working for a has_one and belongs_to relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have two models

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :subscription
end
```

but when I try to create a parent from the child e.g. sub.build_client the foreign key does not get set e.g.

```
>> sub = Subscription.new
=> #<Subscription id: nil, token: nil, user_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, cancelled: nil, active: nil, client_id: nil>
>> sub.save(false);
?> client = sub.build_client
=> #<Client id: nil, server_id: nil, ip: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
>> client.save(false)
=> true
>> sub.client_id
=> nil
>> sub
=> #<Subscription id: 4, token: nil, user_id: nil, created_at: "2010-01-11 06:07:45", updated_at: "2010-01-11 06:07:45", cancelled: nil, active: nil, client_id: nil>
```

It does work if I do client.build_subscription

```
?> client = Client.new
=> #<Client id: nil, server_id: nil, ip: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
>> client.save(false)
=> true
>> sub = client.build_subscription
=> #<Subscription id: nil, token: nil, user_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, cancelled: nil, active: nil, client_id: 4>
>> sub.save(false)
=> true
>> sub
=> #<Subscription id: 5, token: nil, user_id: nil, created_at: "2010-01-11 06:09:32", updated_at: "2010-01-11 06:09:32", cancelled: nil, active: nil, client_id: 4>
>> client
=> #<Client id: 4, server_id: nil, ip: nil, created_at: "2010-01-11 06:09:02", updated_at: "2010-01-11 06:09:02">
>> ^C
```

Ive spent 3 hours fiddling and got nowhere fast. 
Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong, things to check etc

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to your model associations, a `Subscription` is a child of a `Client`.

If you create a subscription first and then create a client as per your first example, Rails has no way of setting a `client_id` foreign key value within the `subscriptions` table because at that point you haven't created the client record, so there's nothing to associate with the subscription. That's why you have to create the parent record (i.e. a client) first and then associate it with a child subscription record using the `build_subscription` method.

Comment: thanks john, i thought this was the case (i did consult the rails guide but couldnt find this explained so wanted to confirm here on stackoverflow). But how come with a has_many belongs to relationship this can be done.

Comment: I just thought as well if it cant be done why is the build method there? If the foreign_id cant be set whats the use for that method in this relationship?

Comment: do you mean the one in my first reply, second reply or both? I might ask this actually as a new question.

Answer (score 3):

it doesn't work both ways, a parent can build a child with the build_association method but not vice versa.

read up : http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_one

Answer (score 1):

In my projects I have many similar associations, but I often forbid setting client_id to null, so I can't create child object without parent object.

Try:

```
sub = Subscription.new
sub.build_client
sub.save
```

It will create and save both objects.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have been fixed in Rails 4.2.5 or earlier. (I'm not sure what the earliest version with the fix is. I've only tested 4.2.5.)

When the parent is saved, after the parent record is inserted, an update is automatically executed to add the parent id to the child record.

However I haven't found any documentation about this behavior, the relevant code, or automated tests, so I'm not sure if it was intentionally fixed and this behavior should be relied on. It might be best to stick with the solutions in the other answers here.

This also seems to be **still broken for has_many** in Rails 4.2.5.

Answer (score 0):

In one of the comments, you ask why the build_client method is there. When you save the client and then check the client_id on sub, it is nil, but if you would have also called

```
sub.save(validate: false)
```

and then checked the client_id on sub, it would exist. So although it required an extra save, it still does the magic of setting up the foreign key for sub.